# Android Studio startActivity inside onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created a project with Zxing barcode

I am using :

**onActivityResult()** :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Intent toStart = null;
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Procces..: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          toStart=new Intent(this,BrowserKotaLama.class);
          // result.getContets() --> is link URL 
         //  Here i want to open new activity with Webview
         // and Webview open that  url 
         // 

        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    if (toStart!=null){
        startActivity(toStart);
    }
}
```

After I run the app I get data from barcode and then it 
shows **"unfortunately  stopped"**

Log Cat : 
04-22 16:50:05.663  24845-24845/example.zxing E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.zxing/example.zxing.BrowserKotaLama}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BrowserKotaLama"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_browser_kota_lama"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="example.zxing.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

at top of manifest

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="example.zxing" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

</style>
```

Comment: Post your logs please

Comment: Sorry , iam new android studio , where i get logs... :D

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: like this ?04-22 16:17:34.731  16970-16970/example.zxing I/SurfaceView﹕ updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true

Comment: Yes like that, look for red block of text mentioning `FATAL` or `Exception` after the crash then copy it and add it at the end of your question.

Comment: `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity` please share your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, i ve edit my question againt... Tq...:D

Comment: Can you please also share your `res\values\styles.xml`?

Comment: actually i want  .. , after i scan barcode --> Get Result --> . this is give a string result  --> url Link, --> open a new activity with Webview ( full screen) and open url .. Sorry my english bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        setScanningMode(true);
        SCANNING_RESULT = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        setResultOfScanning(SCANNING_RESULT);

    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        SCANNING_RESULT = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning Cancelled....", 500)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: SCAN_RESULT is a by default action that return the scan value.